# Conditional Binding Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I am working on an example project (Written in an earlier version of Swift) in my efforts to learn Swift 2, and have run into a problem

I am getting a compile error with this -

```
class func loadMembersFromFile(path:String) -> [Member]
{
var members:[Member] = []

var error:NSError? = nil
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:[]),
json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary,
team = json["team"] as? [NSDictionary] {
for memberDictionary in team {
let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
members.append(member)
}
}
return members
}
```

The errors are:
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSData'

and

Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

My Swift programming experience is quite limited, so I have not been able to find a way to correct these errors. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'NSData'

Means that you don't need conditional binding when result is not optional. But this is not true issue here. Because `NSData` initialiser can throw an error (which is stated in second error) and you may convert it to optional. Here is how your code will look:

```
class func loadMembersFromFile(path:String) -> [Member]
{
    var members:[Member] = []

    var error:NSError? = nil
    if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:[]),
        json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])) as? NSDictionary,
        team = json["team"] as? [NSDictionary] {
            for memberDictionary in team {
                let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
                members.append(member)
            }
    }
    return members
}
```